# How long I should wait for global entry final approval after interview?

Tags: global-entry

I have given interview on 11/14/2019 and still waiting for approval. Officer gave me flyer about Global entry. What should I do? 
How long shall I wait before contacting CBP office where I had interview? 
Note: I am on visa in USA and got conditionally approved in Oct-2019.

I have read through lots of forum where I have seen there application was stuck and got approved when they followed up with CBP office.

Comment: What does the flyer say?

Comment: Mine (a few months ago) took a few days to show up on-line, and a few more to get the mailing.

Comment: Should I wait for 1 week to approach them?

Comment: Flyer is all about global entry. When I start using benefit and all. Similar to one here: Is Global Entry active immediately after the interview?

Comment: Have you logged into your GOES account? What does it say? Did they tell you that you were approved at the interview?

Comment: They didnt say anything specific. Just took my finger prints and picture. GOES still shows conditionally approved.

Comment: Anecdotally, I think it would take less than a month, based on my experience and my wife's. I think mine took about 2 weeks, hers a little longer.

Comment: You mean to say after interview it takes couple of week?

Comment: Recently called CBP office. They told me there system issue and finger print scan taking longer than expected. I should wait.